# Bad method names and what it says about code structure

Tags: oop, methods, method-names

(Apologies in advance if this is a re-post but I didn't find similar posts)

What bad method name patterns have you seen in code and what did it tell you about the code.

For instance, I keep seeing:

```
public void preform___X___IfNecessary(...);
```

I believe that this is bad because the operation X has an inversion of conditions.  Note that this is a public method because classes methods might legitimately require private helpers like this

Comment: These kind of subjective questions should be "community wiki". Edit your question and tick the box, please.

Comment: by 'inversion of conditions' do you mean that the caller should be deciding whether or not `X` is necessary?

Comment: @Jeff Sternal , Yes sorry if my language wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, developers just seem to have a problem using concise wording.  I had one who named a procedure

```
InsertImportQueueRecord
```

I **hated** that name.  I changed it to

```
ImportItem
```

The former not only uses tedious wording to express a simple concept, but unnecessarily reveals implementation details.  Callers did not need to know that a queue was used, and if they did, I would have named it something like `QueueItemImport`, or `ScheduleImport` to point out that the import of the item was being queued or scheduled.  Also, the concept of inserting a record is language in the implementation, not of the problem, and should be avoided.

Comment: Those two names sound like they describe two completely different processes. One of them clearly isn't appropriate, but it's hard to tell which from your answer.

Comment: @Jeff Sternal: Nope, they describe the same thing.  In either case, an item is imported.  One just reveals implementation details that the caller doesn't care about, and uses language of the solution rather than the of problem.  But I mentioned all of that already.

Comment: I certainly agree about the database terminology, and I suppose whether or not you expose the fact of queuing depends on a caller's level of abstraction, so I'll take that back (though in my code, there have definitely been times the fact of queuing has been  relevant to callers, and `ScheduleImport` would have been a better fit)!

Answer (score 2):

thing(), doThing(), and reallyDoThing()

I see this when people aren't entirely clear about the things a function is supposed to do. Maybe it checks if any action is needed first, or it updates caches, or it sends change notifications. Who knows?

Sometimes this is due to a reluctance to change method names. I **hate** this. Functions should do what they sound like they'll do. I change the name if I'm changing functionality significantly anyway, so it forces me to fix up all the callers.

Answer (score 1):

If a concise method name cannot be worked out then it's a good indication that the method is trying to do too much and refactoring should be considered.

An obvious example would be `ValidateFormData_PersistToDB_SendEmail()`.

Although as I'm a C# developer I wouldn't dare use underscores anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another one I noticed recently, A bunch of private methods of the form:

```
private void SOMETHINGBecauseOf__a__(..);
private void SOMETHINGBecauseOf__b__(..);
private void SOMETHINGBecauseOf__c__(..);
```

I can't think of a good reason to have BecauseOf in a method nor to do sort-of the same SOMETHING.  This looks like a good case for a switch/if statement in one method.